# How to use controller in another controller with all its input values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
.controller("transactionTypeController", function($scope, $rootScope, $location, $state, $stateParams, $rootScope){

        $scope.checkReserve = function(){
                //var voucherId = $scope.checked_vouchersId;
                //var transaction = $scope.checked_transactions;
                var base = $scope.base;
                //var newCoupon = $scope.coupons;
                var tL = $scope.checked_transactions.length;
                var input = [];
                for(i = 0; i< $scope.checked_transactions.length; i++){
                    input["transactions["+ i +"][txnId]"] = $scope.checked_transactions[i];
                    input["transactions["+ i +"][txnAmount]"] = JSON.parse($scope.amounts[i].base);
                }
                for(i = 0; i< $scope.checked_vouchersId.length; i++){
                    input["vouchers["+ i +"][id]"] = $scope.checked_vouchersId[i];
                }
                for(i = 0; i< $scope.coupons.length; i++){  
                    input["coupons["+ i +"][couponCode]"] = $scope.coupons[i];
                }
                input['loyaltyId'] = "4ZUZ100001";
                input['redeemPoint'] = '0';
                console.log(input);
                CheckTransactionApi(input);
                $state.go('reservation detail', {'mobile' : mobile, 'loyaltyId' : loyaltyId});
            }
    })
```

Comment: Consider using factories or services to implement functions that should be shared among controllers.

Comment: As @FrankerZ said it better you use factories or services to implement OR else you can use $controller service to instantiate controller into another controller but it might lead to design issues.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments we should always use services or factories to share data among the controller.

In some cases we can also broadcast a value from one controller to other controller.

There is also a way to share data through $rootScope which is again highly not recommended.

But there are also some cases where you want all your values/ functions to be available in other controller even though both of the controller do not have a direct relationship.

In such cases, you can inject $controller to your new controller and use $.extend (or angular.extend) for other controller to be avilable here:

Exa.

```
module.controller('newController', ['$scope', '$controller', function ($scope, $controller) {
    var local = this;
    $.extend(local, $controller('previousController', {$scope: $scope}));
    }]);
```

Comment: Is there any way to define the input as global so that I can pick up its value from any controller

Comment: That is what $rootScope meant for. If you will define any property under $rootScope, those will be available globaly. But  thats not the recommended approach.

I believe you should use constants or factory or service (based on your need) for such values and simply inject those wherever you want. All values from that service will be available. This is the best and recommended way.

Comment: And where is local defined in the above mentioned example

Comment: I have edited the answer.

You can also simply use "this" instead of "local", that should not be a problem.

Comment: I am selecting some values from the above-mentioned controller and I need those selected values in another controller with other values defined in that controller itself, so by creating .factory method is not working, is there any other approach by which I can use the values from one controller to another